# VMWare Player does not show USB devices nor network works

Tags: linux, networking, usb, vmware, vmware-player

I am running VMWare Player under Linux as an ordinary user with no sudo rights. Unfortunately the Player shows no USB devices. Also network inside guest machines does not work. I tried both creating a new virtual machine as well as starting an old one, copied from other computer.

Note: otherwise old machine works as expected and the new one boots properly from CD image.

I also tried to run VMPlayer as another user that has sudo rights as well as root using `sudo vmplayer` and the effect is the same.

As of network I tried both NAT and bridged one.

1. How to make network and USB devices work?
2. Can I run Player as normal user with no root privileges?

Comment: You need to somehow have Sudo permissions. You need to go to the VM settings and then Add USB.  That certainly works in VMware Workstation with Admin Credentials.

Comment: Running as root does not help. It mus be something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally pinpointed the problem.

I have both Virtual Box and VMWare Player installed. When I start VBox VM first VMPlayer finds neither network nor USB devices.

It is necessary to start first VMPlayer Virtual Machine first - it does than see network and USB devices correctly - and VBox VM only later on.

Virtual Box can than also find both network and USB devices,

I still have a problem with mounting pendrives in VMPlayer - the device gets disconnected after a while and no content is seen, but that's a story for another question.